# Page works outside of iFrame, but not in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

We have a form that uses Knockout and jQuery input masks. If we directly load the page (forces SSL), the page works as we expect. If we load the page within an iFrame (parent page non-SSL, iFrame page forces SSL), we don't get any script errors, but the scripts won't work (input masks on phone numbers and dates/add button for a second pet).

Here is our test page with the iFrame: http://www.mankatomn.gov/city-services-a-z/sandbox and here is the iFrame page: https://city.mankatomn.gov/animalregistration. Every search I pull up talks about running the JavaScript in the parent page or having the parent page access the iFrame page. I don't care about that. I just want the iFrame page to run independently.

Do you have any ideas what is going on? In case why you are wondering why we are doing this, our CMS does not support custom forms like this so we had to create and locally host this form.

Comment: Just tried your page and it is working for me. I just see some warnings/errors in the console because you are trying to load non-secure content inside your https page, but that isn't preventing the iframe to load.

Comment: If you try to add pet, it doesn't work. If you click in any of the date or phone fields, you don't get the input masks. The page loads, none of the scripts within the page is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try loading the iframe from the same subdomain. Right now I'm getting this message in Chrome:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://city.mankatomn.gov" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://www.mankatomn.gov".  The frame requesting access has a
>   protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of
>   "http". Protocols must match.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can't. Our site is hosted by a third party. Is there a way to allow this to work? Maybe a cross domain file?

Comment: I just got rid of the iFrame. I spent way too much time working through this.